# Combinatorics questions: returning $n$ hats to their owners

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say there are $n$ hat wearing people entering a restaurant. When they enter, a waiter takes their hats. Upon leaving, the waiter returned the hats. How many ways are there for the waiter to return the hats so that no person gets his original hat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a derangement. Formulas and proofs given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Isn't it inclusion exclusion? All possibilities for dividing the hats so no one gets his are $(n-1)!$. But with if the first person got the hat of the second person? Then the second person also has $n-1$ options for his hat.